# ImportError: No module named 'wordcloud'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am struggling to get wordcloud installed into my environment.
Here is the code I am running:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'wordcloud'
```

I used the `pip install` method in my command prompt to get wordcloud into my environment. It said "requirement already satisfied". I then used the `conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud` method and even after doing this I continue to get the same error.

What am I doing wrong? My Python version is 3.6.2.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gquOz.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y845.png)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp721.png)

Comment: conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud=1.2.1, try this once

Comment: What is the output of conda info wordcloud?

Comment: You might've installed Wordcloud to the wrong python version. A similar problem happened to me once as well- I had to switch Python versions

Comment: hi thank you all for your responses , i very much appreciate your help . the problem is solved . thank you again

Answer (score 25):

first, check the python you are using with:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

then use the path it gives you and run in your jupyter terminal:

```
path/to/python -m pip install some_package
```

Which in my case is:

```
/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip install wordcloud
```

and import in your code:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
```

The source i used:
[can't import](http://takluyver.github.io/posts/i-cant-import-it.html)

Answer (score 5):

```
conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud=1.6.0
```

at anaconda prompt worked for me

Try using latest version of worldcloud

Answer (score 4):

**History:**
On Anaconda prompt, I installed word cloud using conda command. I was able to import, "import wordcloud", at anaconda command prompt. But it was not being imported in Spyder Ipython console, I got the following error:
import wordcloud
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    import wordcloud

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wordcloud'

**Solution:**
1) At Ipython console write following two commands
import sys
print(sys.executable)
we will get following output,
C:\Users\mAge\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe
2) open, anaconda prompt, set its path as given above using change directory command **cd**
3) at anaconda prompt write:
python -m pip install wordcloud
4) [image: Screen shot showing anaconda prompt]
[image: Screen shot showing Spyder Ipython console]

**Tip:** It will also work for the scenario when "wordcloud" is not installed at our system

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, the following helped resolve (based on what @Yasi Es suggested)

In your **iPython notebook**, execute the following to get the path to the executable

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Take the **path-to-the-executable** from the above to execute the following

```
!<path-to-the-executable>/python -m pip install wordcloud
```

Comment: Also for textblob library I had the same problem. It works for that too.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Python 3 version then try this in terminal:
`pip3 install wordcloud`

for python 2.7:
`pip install wordcloud`

Answer (score 0):

Try to install it using the Anaconda prompt. Open the Anaconda prompt from the start menu and use the below command.

**`conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud=1.8.1`**

Answer (score -1):

Run the following command from Anaconda prompt (as administrator):
conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud