# Cannot import Wordcloud or skmultilearn on GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter

When I try to import `Wordcloud` or `Scikit Multilearn` on Jupyter-Notebook running on the Google Cloud Platform, I get the error as shown in the image even though I have just installed the library.
I have tried using `pip` and `pip3` to no avail.
Kindly Help.

[image: no module named wordcloud]

Answer (score 0):

You can foolow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57091706/9687748) 
Solution:

1. At Ipython console write following two commands import sys
   print(sys.executable) we will get following output,
   C:\Users\mAge\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe
2. open, anaconda prompt, set
   its path as given above using change directory command cd
3. at
   anaconda prompt write: python -m pip install wordcloud